# Java Code - NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm making a game and it is giving me a `NullPointerException` which I believe means the variable or what I'm trying to do is not returning a value? I'm using the code below:

```
package OurGame;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Coin extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Image img;

int x,y;
Timer t;
Random r;

        public Coin() {
            x = 50;
            y = 50;

            System.out.println("New coin created: " + x + ", " +y);

            ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/coin.png");
            img = i.getImage();
            System.out.println(i);

            t = new Timer(3000,this);
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            move();

        }

        public void move() {

            setX(r.nextInt(640));
            setY(r.nextInt(480));


        }

        public void setX(int xs) {
            x = xs;
        }

        public void setY(int ys) {
            y = ys;
        }
        public Image getImage(){
            return img;
        }

        public int getX(){
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }


}
```

The error is happening here:

```
        setX(r.nextInt(640));
```

The full error output is below:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at OurGame.Coin.move(Coin.java:46)
    at OurGame.Coin.actionPerformed(Coin.java:40)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I dont see any reason for this to happen but maybe you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialise the variable `r`.  Check out the constructors for [`java.util.Random`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#constructor_summary), for example:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using `r` without ever saying `r = new ...`.

Answer (score 2):

`r` is null. Initialize it first.  Put this in your constructor:

```
r = new Random();
```